# Intermittent Connection fails

Tags: vba, mysql-connector

I have a subroutine that tests to see if a connection to a mysql database is active. If it is not, it opens the connection. But it randomly fails not as expected.

My function:

```
Public oConn As ADODB.Connection

Function InitConn()
' this tests for an active connection to the database and opens it if not already open
' it returns boolean so the calling routine can decide what to do.
    On Error Resume Next
    
    If oConn Is Nothing Then
        Dim str As String
        str = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};SERVER=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;DATABASE=mysqldatabase;PORT=3306;UID=myid;PWD=mypassword;"
        Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
        oConn.Open str
        Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone
        
    End If
    
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
     InitConn = False
     Else
     InitConn = True
     End If
  
   
       On Error GoTo 0
    
End Function
```

The calling routine is most often:

```
If Not InitConn Then 
    msgbox "some appropriate message"
    Exit Sub ' 
endif
SQLstr = "some SQL statement"

Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.Open SQLstr, oConn, adOpenStatic
```

The function always returns True, but the calling subroutine's sql call fails with the error message that the odbc driver does not support the requested properties. Immediately trying again succeeds.

Thinking maybe it was a timing issue with a response from the database, I added
Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone

No effect.
I'm sure I must have a rookie mistake in here somewhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Bob

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` is not doing anything useful there....

Comment: If you will Enable the MySQL General Log prior to testing, you will likely see how MySQL is 'self healing' on the second attempt and does what you ask it to do.  Please post the General Log for confirmation of your success and we can then discuss a way to avoid the aggravation.  Be SURE to turn OFF the GENERAL LOG as soon as possible to avoid filling your storage media, then you will have a REAL PROBLEM.  What is the URL for the base code used as your starter code?  Would like to review it and compare to your existing code.

Comment: This project began life using a 32 bit Mariadb. I moved it over to a shared environment 64 bit MySQL, so unfortunately, I cannot enable logs. But, so many of the errors I saw seemed related to the ODBC driver, that I checked my drivers again. The 64 bit driver was installed, but to make sure I used MySQL connector to UNINSTALL the 32 bit driver and reinstall the 64 bit. It works! I use error trapping to direct new users to install the proper drivers.

Comment: BTW, I found the post by Jason Brady at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66147534/maintain-an-open-connection-to-sql-with-excel-vba to be most thought provoking and helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This project was moved from a 32 bit Mariadb server on my lan to a 64 bit MySQL database on a shared environment. So, I cannot turn on logs.
But I checked my driver. It said it was a 64 bit ODBC driver, but to be sure, I downloaded and uninstalled the 32 bit version, then reinstalled the 64 bit. Everything now works! I don't know how many posts warn about making sure you have the correct driver. I thought I did, but in this case, it paid to be sure the old drivers had been removed.